# NullPointerException Error stopping listview

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hello i am trying to populate a list view from a SQLITE Database. 
im using a custom cursor class to adapt the data and then inflate my layout

```
    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);


}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suspect_list, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.suspect_id);
    textViewId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0))));

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.suspect_name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonSex = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.suspect_sex);
    textViewPersonSex.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

}
```

upon running the code an error is shown through the logcat

```
    05-04 15:10:05.371: D/AndroidRuntime(444): Shutting down VM
05-04 15:10:05.371: W/dalvikvm(444): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sherlock/com.example.sherlock.Suspectview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at com.example.sherlock.Suspectview.onCreate(Suspectview.java:22)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-04 15:10:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  ... 11 more
```

i understand that this error is contracted through the misinterpretation of varibles i cant see in my code where this is going wrong ...

database cursor

```
public Cursor getAll() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SUSPECTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

the activity where the adapter is being used

```
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      Cursor c = db.getAll();
      CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, c);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

any help/insight you can provide will be very helpful

Comment: What is at line 22 of `Suspectview`? Something there is `null`

Comment: Line 22 is the "list.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: `list` is `null`. Are you extending `ListActivity`? Or do you have a `ListView` in your xml with id list?

Comment: the class i extended to `public class Suspectview extends ListActivity` and i also have a `ListView` item in the .xml activity

Comment: what is the id of that `ListView`?

Comment: @codeMagic the id of the `listview` in the xml is _list_ 
i tired adding changing the id to `android.R.id.list` the same error is still occurring
Would it be due to the use of the deprecated function
`super(context, c);`

Comment: Not sure. Debug and check the line where you initialize your `ListView` and see if your `context` is `null`

Comment: Started the debugging...What am i looking for?

Comment: put a breakpoint here `Cursor c = db.getAll();` and see if `list` or `context` is `null`

Comment: Breakpoint added the logcat still shows the same error

Comment: The breakpoint is so you can stop the program there and inspect the values to see what is `null`

Comment: if im reading this right it says that at that point the value is null

Comment: Yes, a value is definitely `null` there. I'm asking if its `list`

Comment: yes the name of the variable is list

Comment: do you have this in your xml for your `listview` `android:id="@+id/android:list"` and change your initialization in java how I have in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

you need to add the `android` namespace since it isn't an `id` you created